# What can be reasons of error "None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route not found" in SymfonyCMF?

Tags: symfony-cmf, doctrine-phpcr

Getting error from file:

/app/vendor/symfony-cmf/routing/src/ChainRouter.php

"None of the chained routers were able to generate route: Route '/cms/routes/can' not found".

I am guessing it should find this route from database table phpcr_nodes, it exists in database:

[image]

but it does not find.

This method call gives this error:

```
$this->router->generate('/cms/routes/can', array(), RouterInterface::ABSOLUTE_URL)
```

Where should I look for? How to make it find the route? There does this method look for routes? Maybe I have to add somewhere and it does not even look to database?

Answer (score 0):

Got an answer - it finds route what is in phpcr_nodes.path but somewhere is done a filtering of those rows, by config. So even if the row exists with such route, it does not find because of config. Do not know where that filtering is done but at least for doing current task was enough.
Somebody can append if know how the filtering of phpcr_nodes rows can be done so router does not find them.